# trying to get the x and y from svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

so i am trying to get the points from the code in the picture
i already made these teeth manually but it`s rly time consuming because i ll go to the roots after the crows :(

i already seen some posts but it doesn`t work with me
i hope u can find and correct the error in the code

[The error and the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbmgD.jpg)

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMR1k.jpg)

```js
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint(); // Created once for document

function alert_coords(evt) {
  pt.x = evt.clientX;
  pt.y = evt.clientY;

  var cursorpt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  console.log("(" + cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y + ")");
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 3056.000000 1504.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" , onclick="alert_coords(evt)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Haworth said, you must declare svg, otherwise he doesn't know on whom to apply `createSVGPoint` so, add an id to your svg element `id="SVG-ElementID"` and get it with

`const svg = document.getElementById("SVG-ElementID");`

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("SVG-ElementID");
const pt = svg.createSVGPoint(); // Created once for document

function alert_coords(evt) {
  pt.x = evt.clientX;
  pt.y = evt.clientY;

  var cursorpt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  console.log("(" + cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y + ")");
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG-ElementID" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 3056.000000 1504.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" , onclick="alert_coords(evt)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable svg does not seem to be defined anywhere. Hence pt is not defined.

I do not know whether this is the full problem, but start by inserting this before the pt=

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
```